# React-Native - iOS - Bluetooth permission

Tags: ios, react-native, bluetooth

Good day,

I am currently facing the following question: Is it possible to request a Bluetooth permission for iOS via a button click? I have already tried several libraries, all of them need the key "NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription" in my Info.plist. However, if this is added, when initially installing and launching the app, it asks if the app X is allowed to access the Bluetooth. But I don't want this, because I want to assign this permission in a registration process. Is this possible at all? I think so, because for example the app "Discord" only asks for this permission at a certain view. So I need help to what extent this is possible and some thought on how to implement this.

Comment: Initialising CBCentralManager will automatically request the permission, so it depends on the implementation of a library when this happens.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm looking for the same.

Comment: No, sorry. I didnt find any solution yet